# How to compare same object instance in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm making an http call that will either return a 200, 412 or 403 statusCode. If it returns an error code, I'll throw an exception

```
if(response.statusCode == 412){
  throw InvalidCredentialsException();
}
else if(response.statusCode == 403){
  throw SalesManUnregisteredException();
}
else{
  throw ServerException();
```

On the repository implementation, i need to catch the error so I can return the appropriate failure response

```
try {
//code
}
catch (e){
   if(e == InvalidCredentialsException())
      return InvalidCredentialsFailure();
   else if(e == SalesManUnregisteredException())
      return SalesManUnregisteredFailure();
   else
      return ServerFailure();
}
```

When I print the vars

```
print(e) //Instance of InvalidCredentialsException
print(InvalidCredentialsFailure()) //Instance of InvalidCredentialsException
```

But when I compare it, it returns false

```
print(e == InvalidCredentialsFailure()) //false
```

**How can I equate these same instances so I can return the failure class according to the exception thrown?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle different types of exceptions you should use the `on` keyword to specify which type you want to catch:

```
try {
  //code
} on InvalidCredentialsException catch (e) {
  return InvalidCredentialsFailure();
} on SalesManUnregisteredException catch (e) {
  return SalesManUnregisteredFailure();
} catch (e) {
  return ServerFailure();
}
```

The last `catch` will catch all other exceptions if another catch could not be found.

And just for info, if you want to compare the type of a object you should use the `is` keyword like `(e is SalesManUnregisteredException)`.